# Как обновить openssl на FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, openssl

Здравствуйте! Не подскажете, как можно обновить openssl на FreeBSD с консоли, не затрагивая других компонентов системы и не обновляя саму систему? Надо избавиться от Heartbleed. Текущая версия OpenSSL 0.9.8y содержит уязвимость. Служба поддержки хостинга говорит не ставить пакеты с портов. Пробовал обновиться через pkg_add -r openssl по новой ветке. Но в системе даже после перезагрузки остается старая версия OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

Ни версий, ни намёков...

```
cd /usr/src
svnlite update
cd secure
make {secure|insecure}
```

*В зависимости от того, что у тебя есть, этот вариант может работать, а может и не работать. Но направление мысли я тебе дал :)*

PS: Странная служба поддержки. Я бы от такого хостинга отказался бы сразу.